# Only allowing numbers to be taken from user input in java

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a little averaging program I have made and, I am trying to only allow it to take in numbers. Everything else works but, I can't seem to figure it out. I am still learning so, any advise or pointers would be awesome!

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class THISISATEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= 10) {
            i++;

            {
                System.out.print("Enter the test score: ");
                int tS = keyboard.nextInt();
                count++;
                sum = (sum + tS);
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }

        System.out.println("The Average is = " + sum / count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is a problem in while?

Comment: Correct I want the user only to be able to enter numbers and if they don't  then, they could be prompted to enter a number again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your while loop use the following code:

```
System.out.print("Enter the test score: ");
while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {//Will run till an integer input is found
    System.out.println("Only number input is allowed!");
    System.out.print("Enter the test score: ");
    keyboard.next();
}
int tS = keyboard.nextInt();
//If input is a valid int value then the above while loop would not be executed   
//but it will be assigned to your variable 'int ts'
count++;

sum = (sum + tS);
```